# Listbox returns System.Data.DataRowView instead of values

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am doing a project for my school, where I have to make a C# Windows Forms application that lets me interact with my PostgreSQL database. I have made a listbox, which is supposed to get the names of the tables from my database, and when I select these names, data from that table is show in the datagridview object in the form. The problem is, however, all my listbox values are System.Data.DataRowView, and datagridview only displays values from the first table in the list.

The code:

```
    DataTable tabulusaraksts = new DataTable();
    DataTable tabula = new DataTable();
    NpgsqlDataAdapter adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
    NpgsqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
    string tab;
    public datubaze()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string connectionstring = "Server=localhost;Port=5432;UserId=postgres;Password=students;Database=retrospeles;";
        //string connectionstring = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};" +
        //       "User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};",
        //        serveris.ToString(), port.ToString(), user.ToString(),
        //        password.ToString(), database.ToString());
        NpgsqlConnection ncon = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionstring);
        NpgsqlCommand listfill = new NpgsqlCommand("select table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables WHERE table_schema = ANY (current_schemas(false));", ncon);
        adapter.SelectCommand = listfill;
        adapter.Fill(tabulusaraksts);
        listBox1.DataSource = tabulusaraksts;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "table_name";
        NpgsqlCommand showtable = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from " + tab +";" , ncon);
        adapter2.SelectCommand = showtable;
    }
public void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        tab = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        adapter2.Fill(tabula);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = tabula;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code should work. I tried it with some test data and `ListBox` was filled with correct values.
To be sure, try to also set `ValueMember` like

```
listBox1.DisplayMember = "table_name";
```

I think the best approach is to add `DataTable` rows to your `ListBox` using loop or Linq list. After filling `tabulusaraksts` iterate through `DataRows` and add them as items to `ListBox`, without setting `DataSource` Something like this (Linq):

```
adapter.SelectCommand = listfill;
adapter.Fill(tabulusaraksts);
listBox1.Items.AddRange(tabulusaraksts.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row[0].ToString()).ToArray());
NpgsqlCommand showtable = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from " + tab +";" , ncon);
adapter2.SelectCommand = showtable;
```

or, using `foreach` loop

```
adapter.SelectCommand = listfill;
adapter.Fill(tabulusaraksts);

listBox1.Items.Clear();
foreach (DataRow row in tabulusaraksts.Rows)
{
    listBox1.Items.add(tabulusaraksts[0].ToString());
}

NpgsqlCommand showtable = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from " + tab +";" , ncon);
adapter2.SelectCommand = showtable;
```

Comment: It worked, however, now when I try selecting a value from the listbox it gives me an error: ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near ";"

Comment: @KristiansKonters don't construct `adapter2. SelectCommand` in `datubaze` method because `tab` is still empty string and gets its value after listbox item is selected. Create it in `listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`method.

Comment: @KristiansKonters marking my answer as solution is a nice way to say thanks :-)